# How can I get callback function in Bootstrap dual listbox on select event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am kind of new to front end development. I am using this [[demo](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/#demoform)] **Bootstrap DualListbox** in my code. When I am moving one(or multiple) items from one list to another, I need to save them to database first. If DB operation successfully performed then and then only that items should get moved to another list.

How can I do that ? I think there must be some callback function present in this library but couldn't find one.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

First, my advice is using another library: http://crlcu.github.io/multiselect/
I use in our code, and shows self very well.

Second, if you prefer to use Bootstrap DualListBox, its trigger onchange event, but only on **first** one select element.

Code: https://github.com/istvan-ujjmeszaros/bootstrap-duallistbox/blob/master/src/jquery.bootstrap-duallistbox.js#L44

So, if you want to use callback, just add calback right after initialising dualbox (runs also in examples page):

```
$('.demo2').bootstrapDualListbox();
$('.demo2').on('change',function(){
    console.log('triggers');
})
```

**UPD**: Only way to check and do actions before actually change elements status is doing things inside library code.

Look at line 208: https://github.com/istvan-ujjmeszaros/bootstrap-duallistbox/blob/master/src/jquery.bootstrap-duallistbox.js#L208

You may create function `actuallyMove()`, copy here contents of `move()` function, and clear `move()` function with you own code.

You own code must check actions, and after that run `move()`.

Also, do this with `moveAll` function.

Maybe better way is updating API of this library and contribute changes with pull request (in this way `move()` function must call something like `this.onbeforechange` and checking result for true or false).

Comment: Library you suggested is nice but unfortunately I can't use it due to some legacy code issue. Also, the problem with 'onchange' event is that I get that event after item is actually moved to other list(not before).

Comment: Thanks @ainu for edit, I agree with you about updating API of this library. But I am still not getting how can I get this.onbeforechange event in my JS code? Please you guide me.

Comment: +1 for the other library. Documentation is a little more sparse but it's much more configurable. Definitely going to use it instead.

Answer (score 5):

Use external listener. Lets configure this for `select` with class `dual`.

Firstly we append configuration of package.

```
$('select.dual').bootstrapDualListbox({
    selectorMinimalHeight: 160
});
```

Next we forget about this package and set our own listener.

```
$('select.dual').on('change',function (e) {
    console.log($(this).val());
})
```

I we want see changes we can buffer state of this.

```
var lastState = $('select.dual').val();

$('select.dual').on('change',function (e) {
    var newState = $(this).val();                     
    console.log(lastState);                        // selected before
    console.log(newState);                         // selected now
    console.log($(lastState).not(newState).get()); // removed elements
    console.log($(newState).not(lastState).get()); // added elements
    lastState = newState;
})
```